# Ionic 2 : Toastcontroller, Toast design is pretty messed up, no related CSS

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

I m trying to use `ToastController` for showing toast notification in my ionic project.

But the problem is that the toast notification design is pretty messed up.

When I `inspect` it to see its CSS, then there is no CSS related to toast. Isn't it inbuilt?  Following is the screenshot.

[image]

Can anybody help me identify the cause for this??

My ionic environment

```
Ionic Framework: 3.5.0
Ionic App Scripts: 1.3.9
Angular Core: 4.1.3
Angular Compiler CLI: 4.1.3
Node: 6.10.3
```

Comment: I believe you can use custom style `cssClass`?Did you tried that?

Comment: You can check here:https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/

Comment: @soorapadman yes I know we can use custom class, but why it is not working out of the box??

Comment: i'm not sure why it is not working . It could be fine if you added your custom css.

Comment: I'm using a lot of toast in my project and all is working fine by default.
Maybe try to update your project, clear npm folder and then run `npm install`. But out of the box, toast works very well